# Particles in Schrödinger QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

In the Schrödinger picture of QFT, the Schrödinger functional equation for the Harmonic oscillators reads:

\begin{equation}
i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi[\phi, t]=\frac{1}{2} \int d^{3} x\left(-\frac{\delta^{2}}{\delta \phi^{2}(\vec{x})}+|\nabla \phi|^{2}+m^{2} \phi^{2}\right) \Psi[\phi, t]
\end{equation}
The $\Psi[\phi, t]$ are momentum eigenstates, i.e.

\begin{equation}
P_{j}\Psi_1[\phi, t]=i \int d^{3} x \phi(\vec{x}) \partial_{j} \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(\vec{x})}\Psi_1[\phi, t]=(k_1)_j\Psi_1[\phi,t]
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\Psi_1[\phi, t]=a^{\dagger}(\vec{k})\Psi_0[\phi, t]=\int d^{3} x e^{-i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}}\left(\omega_{k} \phi(\vec{x})-\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(\vec{x})}\right)\Psi_0[\phi, t]
\end{equation}
I have three questions:

1. Is there an explicit form for $\Psi_1[\phi, t]$. E.g. in QM, a momentum eigenstate is of the form $e^{ipx}$.
2. In which sense is it possible to talk about particles. I.e. why can we say $\Psi_1[\phi, t]$ is a particle with momentum $k_1$. To me $\Psi_1[\phi, t]$ is a wave functional of classical fields. I.e. it tells me, that the probability to find a the field $\phi$ with momentum $k_1$ is 1. But there is no particle involved.
3. In which sense can the 'particle' $\Psi_1[\phi, t]$ have a position. I.e. $\Psi_1[\phi, t]$ is a wave functional of a field $\phi$. It gives the probability amplitude to find a given field $\phi$. In which sense can we associate a position to such an amplitude?

Comment: The explicit eigenfunctionals you're thinking of are probably the "Hermite polynomial times Gaussian" ones except where $\phi$ is a function of space. Those can definitely be written down here. For the other questions, you should read about the wavepacket definition of asymptotic states in the S-matrix. It is certainly not obvious that the wavefunctional of QFT says anything about where particles are.

Comment: 1: $\Psi_1$ is given in Hatfield's QFT book chapter 10. 2: You're solving for the one-particle field associated to a one-particle quantum field operator associated to a multi-particle system of identical particles, each with the spectrum of eigenfunctions that the one-particle field/operator is expanded in, and particle number is not conserved for this system, so you are just talking about the usual KG qft. 3: Since it's just the Schrodinger picture for quantum field operators whose commutation relations are expressed using functional derivatives, the usual qft interpretations apply.

Comment: @bolbteppa Could you maybe expand what you mean by the usual QFT-picture? To me, the picture is that $|\Psi[\phi]|^2$ is the probability to find the field $\phi$ in a certain configuration. But I do not understand how the particle comes in. Do we interpret $\phi$ as a normal wave function. Such that $\phi$ is the probability to find the particle at some point $x^{\mu}$?